# How can I control UIWebView's scroll position for input elements?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

When a user taps an input text box on a web page, UIWebView automatically adjusts its bounds to make space for the device's keyboard, then scrolls and zooms so that the text box is centered in the screen.

While this is great for most situations, I have some text immediately above my input element that tells the user what to type, eg "please type the first, seventh and ninth letters of your password." This text gets scrolled partly off the screen when the text box is tapped, whereas there is lots of whitespace beneath the text box because UIWebView has centered everything neatly.

I have tried using a HTML label to tell UIWebView that the text is attached to the text box, but that didn't work. I'm considering accessing the underlying scrollView directly when the keyboard is activated, but that seems like a dirty hack so I wanted to see if there were a nicer solution first!

Thanks in advance!